# How do I know before hand whether VC6 or VC9 fits me when installing PHP for windows?

Tags: windows, installation

Here :

http://windows.php.net/download/

Is there a way to check whether I should install the VC9 one or the VC6 one programatically?

Answer (score 3):

It states on the left pane of the page you posted:

**Which version do I choose?
If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org you need to use the VC6 versions of PHP**

If you are using PHP with IIS you should use the VC9 versions of PHP

VC6 Versions are compiled with the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler

VC9 Versions are compiled with the Visual Studio 2008 compiler and have improvements in performance and stability. The VC9 versions require you to have the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x86) or the Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x64) installed

Do NOT use VC9 version with apache.org binaries

In you code you would test for apache or iis, if apache, then based on version.

in php use $_SERVER variables
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: What's apache VC9 for if it tells us not to use it?

Comment: you can use it with iis, not apache: Apparently apache.org's binaries are compiled w/ VC6. Mixing 
dynamically-loaded CRT versions creates a similar situation as statically 
linking it: separate heaps, meaning cross-binary memory management will 
cause heap corruption. Just as insidious is the possible difference in 
object size between the two CRT versions. If DLL A assumes a certain object 
is, say, 8 bytes and DLL B assumes 16 bytes, disaster is virtually assured.

Answer (score 2):

The files from apache.org are indeed compiled w/ VC6. However, the Apache files from apachelounge.com are compiled w/ VC9. If you use the apachelounge install, then use VC9 PHP.